# R raster Error in matrix(res) : data is too long

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have a raster object that is fairly large.  When I try to use `aggregate()` or `resample()` I get "Error in matrix(res) : data is too long"

```
aggnl <- aggregate(nl, fact = 33, fun = sum, na.rm = T)

Error in matrix(res) : data is too long
In addition: Warning message:
In for (i in seq(along = band)) { :
  closing unused connection 3 (/var/folders/5_/l71sk6kn29z17n011g8kld5m0000gp/T//Rtmpx252S3/raster///r_tmp_2020-12-20_105058_3864_32951.gri)

newsize <- projectRaster(nl, res = c(1000,1000), crs = "+proj=aea +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=km +no_defs ") #

resample(nl, newsize)

Error in matrix(res) : data is too long
In addition: Warning message:
In for (i in seq(along = band)) { :
  closing unused connection 4 (/var/folders/5_/l71sk6kn29z17n011g8kld5m0000gp/T//Rtmpx252S3/raster///r_tmp_2020-12-20_114316_3864_00648.gri)
```

Here is my raster info:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 104424, 161190, 16832104560  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent     : -2493045, 2342655, 177285, 3310005  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=aea +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : /Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Personal/Monsanto/data/NLCD_2011_Land_Cover_L48_20190424/NLCD_2011_Land_Cover_L48_20190424.img 
names      : NLCD_2011_Land_Cover_L48_20190424 
values     : 0, 95  (min, max)
attributes :
        ID      COUNT Red Green Blue NLCD.Land.Cover.Class Opacity
 from:   0 7854240512   0     0    0          Unclassified       0
  to : 255          0   0     0    0                             0
```